# Get 2 levels up from dirname( __FILE__)

Tags: php, return, parent, filepath

How can I return the pathname from the current file, only 2 directories up?

So if I my current file URL is returning `theme/includes/functions.php`

How can I return "theme/"

Currently I am using

```
return dirname(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**PHP 5.3+**

```
return dirname(__DIR__);
```

**PHP 5.2 and lower**

```
return dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
```

With PHP7 go further up the directory tree by specifying the 2nd argument to `dirname`. Versions prior to 7 will require further nesting of `dirname`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: Is the main benefit from this method over `dirname(__FILE__).'/../';` to remove the possible inconsistency of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Comment: @Patrick I would say that the main benefit of this over your suggestion is that we get the absolute path of the directory instead of a relative path.  Also, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR inconsistencies are generally edge cases as PHP automatically converts *nix style separators into the appropriate Windows style separator for most cases.

Comment: what if you had to go 3+ levels up? Would be nice if dirname's 2nd parameter was `$levels`, thus `dirname(__FILE__, 3);` :-)

Comment: @Patrick another strategy to ensure the correct DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is uses is to wrap the path in realpath()

Comment: From PHP 7 there is a second parameter `levels`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 39):

Even simpler than `dirname(dirname(__FILE__));` is using [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
dirname(__DIR__);
```

which works from php 5.3 on.

Answer (score 4):

```
[ web root ]
    / config.php
    [ admin ] 
        [ profile ] 
            / somefile.php
```

How can you include config.php in somefile.php? You need to use dirname with 3 directories structure from the current somefile.php file.

```php
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php'; 

dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php'; # 3 directories up to current file
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @geo, here's an enhanced dirname function that accepts a 2nd param with the depth of a dirname search:

```
/**
 * Applies dirname() multiple times.
 * @author Jorge Orpinel <jorge@orpinel.com>
 * 
 * @param string $path file/directory path to beggin at
 * @param number $depth number of times to apply dirname(), 2 by default
 * 
 * @todo validate params
 */
function dirname2( $path, $depth = 2 ) {

    for( $d=1 ; $d <= $depth ; $d++ )
        $path = dirname( $path );

    return $path;
}
```

Note: that @todo may be relevant.

The only problem is that if this function is in an external include (e.g. util.php) you can't use it to include such file :B

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but you can also do something like below, using `\..\..\` as many times as needed to move up directory levels.

`$credentials = require __DIR__ . '\..\App\Database\config\file.php';`

Which is the equivalent to:

`$credentials = dirname(__DIR__) . '\App\Database\config\file.php';`

The benefit being is that it avoids having to nest dirname like:

`dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))`

Note, that this is tested on a IIS server - not sure about a linux server, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Also look at using realpath() like `realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../')` to go up two levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../functions.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but sill relevant.

Use:

```
basename(dirname(__DIR__));
```

to return just the second parent folder name - "theme" in this case.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: *(instead of `dirname(dirname(__DIR__));` which returns to full path from / upto the second parent folder)*